# How to use .whereEqualTo and use .startAt on it in Firestore query?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query the documents where the field "lStatus" is equal to active and orderBy the documents, I'm using it for my search bar, here's my code. Thank You!

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(count == 0){
        choose(mFirestore.collection("Listing"));
        onStart();
    }
    else{
        choose(mFirestore.collection("Listing").whereEqualTo("lStatus","Active").orderBy("lMHeadings").startAt(s.toString()).endAt(s.toString() + "\uf8ff"));
        onStart();
        Log.d("tag", "Text: " + s.toString());

    }
```

it doesn't show any Output.

Comment: What does your `choose` function do?

Comment: for adapter of my recycler view

Comment: Please add the content of your `choose()` method. Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo